# How can I read the special element in a very complicated format of data?

Tags: import

I have [a complicated data set](https://pastebin.com/nhnDApae) (see the image below), and I need to read the magnitude of `Etot` from this data set. Any idea how can I do that?

[image: file]

Comment: Please put the contents of the file in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/).

Comment: it is done https://pastebin.com/nhnDApae

Answer (score 2):

Import the data into *Mathematica* as text, line-by-line:

```
raw = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/nhnDApae", {"Text", "Lines"}];
```

Select the lines that contain `Etot`:

```
sl = Select[raw, StringContainsQ[#, "Etot"] &];
```

Finally, use `StringCases[]` with `NumberString` to extract the numerical data, and convert them with `ToExpression[]`:

```
etotList = ToExpression[First[StringCases[#, NumberString]], InputForm] & /@ sl
   {-76137.07, -76237.9692, -76166.3972, -76178.2419, -75963.3368}
```

If you are okay with *undocumented* functions:

```
etotList = Internal`StringToDouble[First[StringCases[#, NumberString]]] & /@ sl
```

Comment: Note that `Internal`StringToDouble` does not return any error if it fails, but simply 0., which might be a pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/nhnDApae", {"Text", "Lines"}];

Join @@ StringCases[data, "Etot   =" ~~ a__ ~~ "EKtot"  :> ToExpression@ a]
```

> {-76137.07, -76237.9692, -76166.3972, -76178.2419, -75963.3368}